# linking things in c++ using object file

Tags: c++, leda

PROBLEM SOLVED:::

I am using LEDA library in c++.

```
command used to make object file.

g++ -I$LEDAROOT/incl -c mult.cpp

this command runs fine
```

I am getting eroor while linking step.

**HERE IS THE EROOR**

```
varun@Kinley:~/Documents/LEDA/test/numbers$ g++  -L$LEDAROOT mult.o -lleda -lX11 -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I need to install some package,because when I googled this error the most of problems are solved by installing some package .

I didn't find lx11 error

some of the eroor messages that I googled.

> error 1
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status
>
> error 2
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Links where I find these posts

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/21069-collect2-ld-returned-1-exit-status

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-usrbinld-cannot-findlc-error/

Do  I need to install some package  or there is some other problem

Answer (score 0):

Could be two things

1) The X11 library is installed in a non-standard path. Use the search command to see if libX11.a or libX11.so is available on your system. If yes add the directory path to the -L option.

2) You are missing the libX11 library. 
In this case, login as admin and use yum (assuming linux) to install this library.
Eg:

"yum install libX11.i386" or "yum install libX11.x86_64", depending on your architecture (32 bit or 64 bit).